# Post data to PHP with AJAX and read Results in PHP (USING Post)

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, highcharts

I want to show data recieved from **MySQL** in **Highchart.js** graphic. For that, I'm using two textboxes which being entered to date informations. Finally, using a single button which calls function (chart.php). By the way, I'm getting date informations and sending to **mysql.php** with **$.post** method in the function. Then I want to get MySQL datas to show in **Highchart.js**. But program is giving me empty array. Actually, array have  a lot of datas, because function(data) is showing datas in the **($.post)**.

**chart.php**

```
function zaman_al()
    {

        var baslangic=document.getElementById('rest_example_3').value;            
        var son=document.getElementById('rest_example_4').value;

        if (baslangic=="" || son=="") 
            {
                alert("Lütfen Tarih bilgisi Giriniz !!!");
            }
        else
        {

            baslangic = new Date(baslangic); 
            baslangic = baslangic.getTime(); 

            son = new Date(son); 
            son= son.getTime(); 


            if (son<=baslangic) 
                {
                    alert("Geçersiz Tarih Girişi !!!");

                }

            if (son>baslangic)
            {

                var veri={'baslama':(baslangic/1000),'bitirme':(son/1000)};
                $.post('mysql.php',veri,
                    function(data)
                    {

                        alert(data);

                        $(function () {
                            $('#kku').highcharts({
                                chart: {
                                    type: 'spline'
                                },
                                title: {
                                    text: 'Snow depth at Vikjafjellet, Norway'
                                },
                                subtitle: {
                                    text: 'Irregular time data in Highcharts JS'
                                },
                                xAxis: {
                                    type: 'datetime',
                                    dateTimeLabelFormats: { // don't display the dummy year
                                        month: '%e. %b',
                                        year: '%b'
                                    },
                                    title: {
                                        text: 'Date'
                                    }
                                },
                                yAxis: {
                                    title: {
                                        text: 'Snow depth (m)'
                                    },
                                    min: 0
                                },
                                tooltip: {
                                    headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br>',
                                    pointFormat: '{point.x:%e. %b}: {point.y:.2f} m'
                                },

                                plotOptions: {
                                    spline: {
                                        marker: {
                                            enabled: true
                                        }
                                    }
                                },

                                series: [{
                                    name: 'Winter 2007-2008',
                                    // Define the data points. All series have a dummy year
                                    // of 1970/71 in order to be compared on the same x axis. Note
                                    // that in JavaScript, months start at 0 for January, 1 for February etc.
                                    data: [


                                        <?php   

                                                $veri=explode('"',$sonuc);

                                                for ($i = 0; $i < count($veri); $i++) 
                                                {
                                                    if(($i%4)==1)
                                                    {
                                                        echo "[".$veri[$i].","; // time
                                                    }

                                                    if(($i%4)==3)
                                                    {
                                                        echo $veri[$i]."],\n"; // sensor_value
                                                    }
                                                };

                                        ?>

                                    ]
                                }]

                            });
                        });
                    }); 
            }  
        }
    }
```

Above code for button function. By the way.

**chart.php**

```
                            <b>Başlangıç Zamanı :</b>&emsp;</td>
                            <td><input style="border-radius:15px" type="textbox" name="rest_example_3" id="rest_example_3" value="" /></td>
                            <td ><br><br><br></td>

                    </tr>

                    <tr>

                            <td><b>Bitiş Zamanı :</b>&emsp;</td>
                            <td><input style="border-radius:15px" type="textbox" name="rest_example_4" id="rest_example_4" value="" /></td>
                            <td ><br><br><br></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td ><br><br><br></td>
                        <td><input type="button" style="border-radius:15px; background-color:lightgreen; float:right" width="100" value="Get Chart" onClick="zaman_al()"> </td>  
                        <td ><br><br><br></td>
                    </tr>

                </table></center>  

                <div id="kku"></div>
```

When I sent to data **mysql.php** in the **($.POST)**, **mysql.php** is giving me **notice:Undefined xxx**.

[mysql.php error statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cct09.jpg)

By the way, **mysql.php** is follow as:

```
<?php

$baslangic =$_POST['baslama'];  // -> notice: Undefined index: baslama
$son=$_POST['bitirme'];         // -> notice: Undefined index: bitirme

//$baslangic=1445780257;    ->    correct result for it
//$son=1445780290;          ->    correct result for it

//echo $son;
//echo $baslangic;
//settype($son, "int");
//settype($baslangic, "int");
//echo gettype(1445780290);
//echo gettype($son);

$baglanti= new mysqli("localhost","root","","deneme_kou");  

$sql = "SELECT zaman,sensor_deger FROM sensor WHERE zaman>='$baslangic' AND zaman<='$son'";
$res=mysqli_query($baglanti,$sql);

$result = array();

while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($res))
{
    $result[]=array($row["zaman"],$row["sensor_deger"]);
}

$sonuc=json_encode(array($result));

echo json_encode(array($result));

?>
```

When I wrote **`$baslangic=1445780257 $son=1445780290`;** instead of **`$baslangic = $_POST['baslama']; $son=$_POST['bitirme']`**, I can get correct result and show in **`highchart.js`**.

Could you help me about this problem?

Comment: Your PHP isn't receiving the post data. In your PHP script, do a var_dump($_POST); exit; and then monitor the network pane in inspect element for this ajax request and then view the response. This will show you what post data you DO have access to. Likely, though, it will be empty because you're not posting it correctly with the javascript. I can't find the specific error, but I also can't match your syntax to any found on this page: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/ Perhaps you should consider adding ,"json" as a final argument to the $.post() ?

Comment: Looks like your not posting any values.  check your zaman_al() function to make sure you have values in your post.

Comment: The syntax for the `$.post()` looks OK, so you should first try looking at the browser's network tab (like @MikelBitson suggested) and see what kind of data is being sent

Comment: I wrote veri=JSON.stringify(veri); alert(veri) and program gave {"baslama":1445720400, "bitirme":1445720800}. But program is still giving notice:Undefined baslama ....

Comment: thanks you for all :) Actually, my program is right, but ı get error ( undefined) because of I want to  open mysql.php  from browser. Because when I opened mysql.php, I didn't data ($baslangic = $_POST['baslama']; $son=$_POST['bitirme'] ) and program didn't find data. program got me error because of that.